# JScrollPane not showing on scroll

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am creating a GUI and I have a problem.

I have a `JPanel` with info, and at the end of it, I have another `JPanel` with a `JScrollPane` to scroll when needed.

This is the code:

```
public BreadCrumpsDisplayer(JPanel father)
{
    this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(200, 200, 200));
    this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(father.getSize().width, height));
    javax.swing.GroupLayout MigasDePanLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(MigasDePanLayout);
    sp = new JScrollPane(this);
    sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        JButton ab = new JButton("HHH");
        ab.setSize(100,50);
        ab.setLocation(i*300, 0);
        this.add(ab);
    }
    father.add(sp, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    addMouseListener(this);
addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

My class is a `JPanel`. I set the color and the size. Then, I create the ScrollPane with my class as the view parameter of the constructor. Set the Horizontal (when the buttons inside are out of my view) and vertical(never)

Then, I create 8 buttons and put them in my panel.

The problem is that I cannot see them all, when I try to move the ScrollBar it doesn't work.

A snapshot

[image]

I dont know why I cannot see the rest of the buttons.

PD: My class is a component of another JPanel.

Comment: You're putting each of buttons on positions which are multipes of 300. Isn't your whole bar smaller than that?

Answer (score 4):

You aren't using the GroupLayout properly and therefore the panel doesn't have a proper preferred size. You can't just add components to the panel. You also need to specify the GroupLayout constraints. I suggest you don't use a GroupLayout. It was designed for IDE's that use a single layout manager.

```
ab.setSize(100,50);
ab.setLocation(i*300, 0);
```

The point of using a Layout Manager is to let the layout manager determine the size/location of a component. When you use a layout manager properly, then the scrollbars on the scrollpane will work automatically.

I suggest you could use either a `FlowLayout` or  horizontal `BoxLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples of each of the above layouts.